# Developing Android apps using Samsung SDK on standard emulator. Is it possible to run Samsung's framework at all?

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-mobile-sdk

Simple question: is it possible at all to develop Android apps with any Samsung SDK on the standard emulator?
It lacks of Samsung components and framework; but, are they available somewhere for installation? Or do I need to use a real Samsung device?

Specifically, I was taking a look at the MediaControl lib, but it needs the AllShare component; its apk (although is possible to find it around) won't install on the emulator.

Maybe I'm missing something (I'm new to the Samsung SDKs) but I'm not able to find any references.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use genymotion for personal use. In that you can download even samsung mobile instance

Comment: Well, worth a try, thanks.

Comment: I can't find a free version :(

Comment: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download <br>Below you can find link to download genymotion for personal use